# 404 not found error when sending a delete request from angular 5 project to .net web api

Tags: .net, angular, api, angular5, angular6

I am getting a "DELETE http://localhost:51352/api/Account/undefined 404 (Not Found)" when sending a delete request from angular 5 to .net web api.

Here is my user.component.ts in angular

```
 delete(id){
  this.spinner.show();
  this._userService.deleteUser(id).subscribe(() => {
  this.spinner.hide();
  this.toastr.successToastr('User registration successful');
  this._messageService.clear('c');
  this.getUser();
}, err => this.spinner.hide()); }
```

Here is my deleteUser function in the user.service.ts file.

```
deleteUser(Id: string){
  return this.http.delete(this.remoteServerBaseUrl + '/api/Account/' + Id)
}
```

}

```
export class UserListDto {
  Id: string;
  UsernName : string;
  Email : string;
  FirstName : string;
  LastName : string;
}

export class UserEditDto {
  Id : string;
  UserName : string;
  Email : string;
  FirstName : string;
  LastName : string;
}
```

Here is my users.component.html file.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
                <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>&nbsp;Actions&nbsp;<i class="caret"></i>
                </button>
                <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="edit(user.id)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</a></li>
                    <!-- <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="resetPassword(user)"><i class="fa fa-redo"></i> Reset Password</a></li> -->
                    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="delete(user.Id)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td *ngFor="let col of cols">{{col.type ? col.type.transform(data[col.field], col.arg1, col.arg2, col.arg3, col.arg4) : data[col.field]}}</td>
          </tr>
        </ng-template>
```

Here is my WebApiConfig.cs file in .Net.

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:51352", headers: "*", methods: "*"));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Apply camelCase notation
        var settings = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
        settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
}
```

Your help will really be appreciated

I have updated the user.component.html file.

```
<ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="edit(data.id)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</a></li>
                    <!-- <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="resetPassword(user)"><i class="fa fa-redo"></i> Reset Password</a></li> -->
                    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="delete(data.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a></li>
                </ul>
```

After trying this on postman. Api works well so I feel it is coming from the angular app not passing the `id`.Image from postman below.
[Image from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdBuM.png)

Comment: please read how to post  question. if  you have add some code instead of image its will  better understanding for viewer

Comment: Did you tried `GET` instead on `DELETE` in you `user.service.ts`

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek . Sorry, am quite new in asking questions here. I have edited the question properly

Comment: @WaelAbbas . Yes GET works fine as I use it in another controller to getById but does not work in delete. I have tested my api on postman and it works well but not using angular

Comment: Try printing `this.remoteServerBaseUrl + '/api/Account/' + Id` and if the id is properly appended to the URL

Comment: Post full `AccountController` code

Comment: @WaelAbbas I have updated the question above and have included the full code for the AccountController. Thanks

Comment: Can you add the whole user.component.ts please?

Comment: I have added screenshot of api test using postman and it works good

Answer (score 0):

You have an uppercase typo error in your user.component.html file.

You pass `user.Id` instead of `user.id` to the component `delete` function.

The `Id` property is probably undefined in your `user` object.

Comment: I have changed it to `user.id` that is small letters but I still get same result.

Comment: Are you sure? Log what your user object is.
(click)="delete(user.Id) looks like the error to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add route attribute `[Route("api/Account/{Id}")]` to `DeleteUser(string id)` method  in your controller so `id` parameter can be readied from api url

Also You need to send `Id` as string to api

Update `deleteUser` function in the `user.service.ts` file as below

```
return this.http.delete(`${this.remoteServerBaseUrl}/api/Account/"${Id}"`')
```

Comment: After updating to return `this.http.delete(`${this.remoteServerBaseUrl}/api/Account/"${Id}"`)` I get the error "http://localhost:51352/api/Account/%22undefined%22 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Where do you fill `user` object? Also try to change the url to `'api/Account/DeleteUser/'`

Comment: The first problem you have to fix is that you get undefined in your url. You are not sending your id from the html correctly. Unless the id is undefined?

Comment: @MichaelKarénI I have seen where I made a mistake. Silly me. I used `user.id` instead of `data.id` and at least solved the undefined error but now its a `DELETE http://localhost:51352/api/Account/null 404 (Not Found)` that comes up.

Comment: @WaelAbbas I have an error on my part from your question. I have corrected from `user.id` to `data.id` but now get a `DELETE http://localhost:51352/api/Account/null 404 (Not Found)` error.

Comment: @K.ODeveloper add attribute `[Route("/api/Account/{Id}")]` to `DeleteUser(string id)` method  in controller

Comment: And add [HttpDelete]